# what is difference between "\n" and '\n' in strcat function?

Tags: c

sorry for my poor english,
I made a program that read Lines from File1 and print it Backwards to File2
in File1 all Lines has \n at the end except the Last one It doesn't have to be a snowman. If I just run program without strcat \n in to Last Line then the output File2 shows like bottom. So I try to strcat \n to Last Line in that process strcat(buffer[9], "\n"); was worked but strcat(buffer[9], '\n'); was not. Why this happened?

```
// FILE 1
Do you wanna build a snowman?\n
Come on lets go and play\n
I never see you anymore\n
Come out the door\n
It's like you've gone away-\n
We used to be best buddies\n
And now we're not\n
I wish you would tell me why!-\n
Do you wanna build a snowman?\n
It doesn't have to be a snowman.

// FILE 2
It doesn't have to be a snowman.Do you wanna build a snowman?\n
I wish you would tell me why!-\n
And now we're not\n
We used to be best buddies\n
It's like you've gone away-\n
Come out the door\n
I never see you anymore\n
Come on lets go and play\n
Do you wanna build a snowman?\n


include <stdio.h>
include <string.h>
define LINE 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        puts("Usage : hw9 inputFileName OutputFileName");
        exit(1);
    }


    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    char *buffer[15][LINE];
    char *buffer2[15];


    if(fp == NULL || fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("File open error! \n");
        return 1;
    };

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer[i],LINE,fp)!=NULL)
    {
        buffer2[10-i] = buffer[i];
        printf("buffer2[%d] : %s\n", 10-i, buffer2[10-i]);

        i++;
    }

        working!
    strcat(buffer[9], "\n");

        error! why?
    //strcat(buffer[9], '\n');

    fprintf(fp2, buffer2[1]);


    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; ++i)
        fprintf(fp2, buffer2[i]);

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: RTFM. `strcat` expects `const char*` as a second parameter. `"\n"` is just that, `'\n'` is a `char`.

Comment: How about const char *tmp[] = '\n'; strcat(buffer[9], tmp); isn't this tmp represent const char *?

Comment: yes I failed to compile it.  const char *tmp[1];

 tmp[0] = '\n'; this was the way to assign '\n'to *tmp array, and I tried with this strcat(buffer[9], tmp[0]); of course it not worked. I think from this const char * source == const char *tmp[0] has matched but because of '\n' it broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, double quotes are used to represent a string constant while single quotes represent a single character.

`"\n"` is a string constant containing the `\n` character followed by a null byte terminating the string and has type `const char []`, while `'\n'` is the character `\n` and has type `int` (as do all character constants).

The `strcat` function expects a `const char *` as the second argument.  A string constant like `"\n"` qualifies since arrays (in most contexts) decay to a pointer to the first element.  Passing `'\n'` does **not** work because you're passing an `int` to a function which expects a pointer.  This results in the encoded value of `\n` being treated as a pointer which `strcat` attempts to dereference, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

takes const char* parameter just like "\n" is .. but '\n' is just of type char